# Сделать изображение по центру

Tags: html, css

Каким образом выравнить изображение, чтобы оно сверху автоматически отступало, как показано на скриншоте? Пытался химичить с `vertical-align`, но ничего не вышло.

[image]

```css
.item {background: #cccccc; text-align: center; height: 250px}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="image">
      <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cat-power/128/cat_eyes.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0e2dLzqp/1/

Решение **не должно** быть на CSS3 и на JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vertical-align` работает только при наличии `line-height`, в данном конкретном случае, у родителя.

```
.image {
    background: #cccccc; 
    text-align: center; 
    height: 250px; 
    line-height: 250px;
}
.image img {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо Вам огромное <3

Comment: height можно было и не задавать.

Comment: @ModaL, не за что =)  @vadim-kot, я не знаю, для каких именно целей его добавил топикстартер. Вдруг без `height` не будет работать его дальнейшая задумка.